# SonarQube doesn't see method reference

Tags: java, sonarqube, method-reference

I have private method in my class.

```
public class MyClass {
     public void method(){
         ....
         List<String> filteredPaths = Arrays.asList(paths).stream().filter(this::validate).collect(Collectors.toList());
         ....
     }
     private boolean validate(String path){
        ...
     }
}
```

I see major issue:

```
Private method 'validate' is never used.
```

Is this issue known?

How to fix it? workarounds?

Comment: It is a bug: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-583

Comment: @user432 thus you can answer the question)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a known bug: please see http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-583

To provide more context here : This unused private method is relying on an old implementation and is (at time of writing my answer) being migrating to rely on semantic analysis and not only bytecode analysis.